# location.reload after ajax post

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I have a $.ajax() call that does some server-side updates.  After it's finished (in the "success" function), I call location.reload(true) to refresh the page.  I do want the "true" there because I do want the new changes to appear, as opposed to getting the cached version of the page that doesn't have them.  This all works nicely in FF (27.0.1).  However, it is NOT working in IE 10.  And, it is not working in Chrome (33.0.1750.149).  (I'm working in asp.net MVC, in case that matters.)

In fact, the entire ajax call is not made (ie: the updates don't even happen on the server).  When I comment out the line, the ajax call works perfectly, but obviously no reload.

I tried all the following options in IE 10.  Some reload the page, just the cached version.  Some break the entire ajax call.
window.location.reload(true); --> breaks ajax call
window.location.reload(); --> breaks ajax call
window.location.href = window.location.href --> works, but cached version is reloaded

Any other ideas?  I'm even open to doing a full ajax/jquery redirect to the page?

Here's the ajax function:

```
function ExecuteFlagAssign() {
.....//some code here...not important....//

     $.ajax({
                type: 'POST',
                url: '/Services/poAJAX.asmx/SetPOInfo',
                data: "{inPOCombinedIDList: \'" + masterItemIDList + "\', inParameters: \'" + JSON.stringify(paramObj) + "\'}",
                dataType: "json",
                contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8;",
                success: UpdateCompleteFlagAssign(callFrom),
                error: UpdateErrorFlagAssign
            });
    }

    function UpdateCompleteFlagAssign(callFrom) {
        if (callFrom == "po_detail" || callFrom == "so_detail" || callFrom == "so_detail_top") {
            window.location.reload(true);
        }
    }
```

Just to add one more point (don't think it's important, but who knows):  the button that calls the javascript is on a popup.  However, it's not a real modal popup.  It's actually just a hidden div that gets a high z-index (so it appears) when it's requested. 
This javascript code is all on the main page (not the partial view that has the popup display).

So, when I comment out the window.location.reload(true) line, it all works, ajax call fires, updates are made, etc.  Just no reload.  When I DON'T comment out the line, page DOES reload, but ajax call is not fired/updates don't occur.  (no error in developers tools in IE)

Any ideas?  I'm really baffled.  I'm open to work-arounds here.....

(I know one work-around is to make this a full postback to the server, instead of an ajax call that then refreshes the page.  But, that's a decent amount of work.  And, there are some pages that call this function that DON'T require a refresh...so it's kinda nice to just use the same ajax call in all cases.)

I really appreciate anyone's time & help on this!!!

Comment: even after adding: <META HTTP-EQUIV="CACHE-CONTROL" CONTENT="NO-CACHE"> --> still not refreshing, even in FF, with location.href=location.href.  Is there any way in the world that the page is refreshing BEFORE the database update actually occurred?  I'm certainly assuming not, since it's in the "ON SUCCESS" of the ajax call..........

Comment: ok, this is a bit strange, maybe someone has thoughts on it...? in any case, with the meta tag & putting the location.href=location.href IN THE success function, inline (not calling another method, UpdateCompleteFlagAssign) seems to be working.......

Comment: oh! now I see the bug. You're calling UpdateCompleteFlagAssign(callFrom) immediately, but you instead need to pass the function (without calling) it to the ajax call. Get rid of those perens!